# How to send a serializable object with nonserializable children from one Android activity to another using intent

Tags: java, android, object, android-intent, serializable

I have a seralisable class with nonserializable child. I want to send the object of this class from ona android activity to another, but I cannot. The classes are following:

```
public class A implements Serializable{

/**
 * generated serial version UID
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3445290513860716092L;

private B b;

public A () {}

public B getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
}
}
```

Where the class B is not serializable

```
public class B{

private int ID;
protected String name;

public B() {}

...
}
```

I use putExtra method of Intent to send object.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
b.setID(1);
b.setName("Name");
a.setB(b);
i.putExtra("object", a);
startActivity(i);
```

An error occurs when activity starts. What is wrong?

Comment: You answered your question in your question itself - it's not serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serialize a class, all its children MUST be serializable. You cannot do it with non-serializable children. You will have to make all its children (and their children too) serializable.